# reverse list and append it to istelf

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Im trying to get a list to inputted in a function, and then the output would be the list, and then the reverse of the list added onto itself but for some reason whenever I reverse the variable reversal, it reverses list as well

```
def mirror(list):
    reversel = list
    reversel.reverse()
    list.extend(reversel)
    return list

    
    
    
test = ["alpha", "beta"]
print(mirror(test))
```

**output**

```
['beta', 'alpha', 'beta', 'alpha']
```

**desired output**

```
["alpha","beta","beta","alpha"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution without using `reverse()`.

```
def mirror(list_to_mirror):
    
    reversel = list_to_mirror
    reversel = reversel[::-1]
    #This is an equivilant to reverse()
    list_to_mirror.extend(reversel)
    
    return list_to_mirror

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test = ["alpha", "beta"]
    print(mirror(test))
```

Comment: You make this overly complex by introducing the `reversel` variable. Just drop the first to code lines in the function and use `list_to_mirror.extend(list_to_mirror[::-1])`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use slicing:

```py
def mirror(lst):
    return lst + lst[::-1]

test = ["alpha", "beta"]
print(mirror(test)) # ['alpha', 'beta', 'beta', 'alpha']
```

An issue in the provided code is that (i) `reversel = list` (but don't use `list` as a name) does *not* copy the object, and (ii) `reverse()` reverses the list *in place*. These two lines of code, therefore, reverse the list `list` (as well as `reversel`). As a result, now `list` and `reversel` **both** are `["beta", "alpha"]`. Then after `list.extend(reversel)`, `list` becomes what you observe.

Also, there is another subtle issue; it is not generally recommended doing both of the following: (i) modify a given object, and (ii) return the object; this might cause confusion (I believe). It is better to do only one of them; modify an object in place (like `reverse`), or don't modify the object but return a modified copy of the object (like `reversed`).

Answer (score 0):

This should work -

```
def mirror(list):
    reversel = [i for i in list]
    reversel.reverse()
    list.extend(reversel)
    return list

    
    
    
test = ["alpha", "beta"]
print(mirror(test))
```

when using '=' it stores the location of the variable. So when using a function like reverse, both values change.

Answer (score -1):

A way that doesn't require creating and discarding a copy:

```
def mirror(lst):
    lst += reversed(lst)
    return lst
```